# OMP Optimizing nested loop with if statement

Tags: c, loops, nested, openmp

I have the following few lines of code that I am trying to run in parallel

```
void optimized(int data_len, unsigned int * input_array, unsigned int * output_array, unsigned int * filter_list, int filter_len) {

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j < filter_len; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data_len; i++) {
            if (input_array[i] == filter_list[j]) {
              output_array[i] = filter_list[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just putting the pragma statement has really done wonders, but I am trying to further reduce the run time of this code. I have tried many things ranging from array padding to collapsing the loops to creating tasks, but the only thing that has seemed to work thus far is loop unrolling. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could possibly due to further speed up this code?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc along with -O3 optimization

Comment: If you're running on an Intel processor, look into Intel Intrinsics:
http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Comment: This suggestion depends somewhat on the optimization level:  use register attribute, use pointers, not names and offsets, increment the pointers, not pointer+offset.

Comment: use the align #pragma on each of the data areas to allow aligned access to RAM.

Comment: If the compiler/CPU allows it, use unroll $pragma so instruction fetches are reduced by making use of any internal instruction loop capabilities of the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing pure memory accessing. That is limited by the memory bandwidth of the machine. 
Multi-threading is not going to help you much. gcc -O2 already provide you SSE instruction optimization. So it may not help either to use intel instruction directly. You may try to check 4 int at once because SSE support 128 register (please see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html and google for some example) Also to reduce the amount of data helps, by using short instead of int if you can.

Comment: The natural size of the memory references (typically 32 bits now a days) means using int will be faster as the whole 32 bits is moved in one operation.

Comment: You are addressing CPU's effort. But in his case memory access time dominates. So my experience is that smaller data will help.